# build a c# project into two identical dlls with different assembly names and guids

Tags: c#, build, prebuild

I am wondering if it is possible to build a project into two identical dlls that have different assembly names and guids. 
similar to the post build macros that allow one to copy and rename the dll - I imagine something like a pre-build command to build dll #1 with assembly name 1 and guid 1 and then build the same project again with assembly name 2 and guid 2.
I have searched the net but everything I could find pointed to the usual post build macros for renaming the dll file.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't done that specifically, but I can imagine you can create a second project with a different assembly name/GUID, [link files from the source project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234), and you can compile both simultaneously. You can use [Project Linker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/273dbf44-55a1-4ac6-a1f3-0b9741587b9a) to help keep the projects synchronized. EDIT: I've done this to simultaneously compile Silverlight and Xamarin.Android projects from the same source code.

Comment: great suggestion! didnt know project linker

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done that from a *single* project, but you can create a *second* (or third or fourth) project with a different assembly name/GUID, [link files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234) from the source project, and you can compile both simultaneously from the same solution.

You can use [Project Linker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/273dbf44-55a1-4ac6-a1f3-0b9741587b9a) to help keep the projects synchronized.

Comment: @timkado: VS2013 installation instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21630385/1269654