# How can I get started with Xamarin from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, nugetgallery

I want to port a Compact Framework/Windows CE app to Xamarin to create Android and IOS (and possibly Windows Phone) "versions." I reckon I need Windows 8 for Windows Phone (8) but for now I thought I could get started with Android and IOS in moving this prehistoric app into the 21st century.

According to [this article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/cross_platform_visual_studio_project_setup_walkthrough/), I first need "Project linker" and can NuGet it, but searching for it via Tools > Extensions and Updates in VS 2013 returns no search results.

That article says you need VS 2012 or better; the [direct link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e730577-d11c-4f2e-8e2b-cbb87f76c044) to "Project Linker," though, says it supports VS 2010.

Where do I go from here?

### UPDATE

I went [here](https://xamarin.com/visual-studio), and am in the processing of downloading.

### UPDATE 2

[Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introduction_to_mobile_development/), it says, "Modern Integrated Development Environment (IDE) – Xamarin uses Xamarin Studio on Mac OS X, and also Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio 2010 on Windows."

Yet in VS 2013, I *do* have project types now for Android and IOS*, so I reckon that's just a typo (hasn't been updated)?

- although I don't have a Mac, so that is not possible for me right now; also, since I'm still on Windows 7 at work, Windows 8 Phone apps are not yet a possibility, either. So *at present*, Xamarin within Visual Studio is simply a replacement for Eclipse/Java in the creation of Android apps.

### UPDATE 3

I've been waiting for something better than PhoneGap, and I think maybe I've found it. If MS were to buy this company and bake Xamarin into Visual Studio -- voila!/yowza/wow! The cats in Cupertino will have to reach for the Pepto-Bismol!

Comment: The Xamarin for Visual Studio is still maturing (of course); I ran into a minor bug with it today and reported it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/837459/why-does-visual-studio-make-the-resources-folders-uppercase-when-the-android-sdk-requires-them-to-be-lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit outdated and there's a much better approach available today.

You can use Portable Class Libraries (PCL) to share code across project spanning iOS, Android,  Windows (Phones) and even OSX.

See [this article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) (and where it leads) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly agree with @poupou that PCL's are the way to go (if possible). I would recommend [James Montemagno's app](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyExpenses) on github. He just created this for channel9 using VS 2013. I just created a cross-platform app based off of this and it worked out well. I would only use the file-linking for the platform specific implementations with compiler directives. This can be seen in his ServiceRegistrar class in said app.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630385/1134836) actually explains how to get the 2012 Project Linker to work with 2013 if you still want to go that route and gives a link to the extension.

Also, you may want to check out MvvmCross. It is open-source, has a large user-base and following, and really helps with maximum code re-use. Best part, it uses PCLs and all of it's features (plugins) are available via nuget.

I would recommend reading the article @poupou posted, watching James' channel9 videos on his github page, and (if you want to check out mvvmcross) watch @slodge's [N+1 videos](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/) on mvvmcross.